# Understanding stderr stdout redirection

Tags: shell, stdout, stderr

I'm having trouble understanding what's going on in this line; can someone break it down for me?

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2 > $SOMEFILE 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is saving the current files used for standard output and standard error to file descriptors 3 and 4, respectively, before redirecting standard output to a file and standard error to the same file. In detail:

- `3>&1` - makes file descriptor 3 a duplicate of 1, so that any writes to 3 go to the file currently bound to 1
- `4>&2` - makes file descriptor 4 a dupicate of 2, with the same meaning as `3>&1`
- `> $SOMEFILE` - changes file descriptor 1 to point to `$SOMEFILE`
- `2>&1` - makes file descriptor 2 also reference `$SOMEFILE`